# Maximum length limitation in List in Erlang

Tags: string, list, erlang

If I store 15 character strings as elements of a list in Erlang. What will be the maximum elements in the that list.

1. Is it depend on the memory of the system?
2. Is there no limitation for list length in Erlang?

Comment: FYI it would be way more efficient to store them as binaries, if possible. A 15 char string will use 31 words of memory = 248 bytes on 64 bit, while a UTF-8 encoded binary of 15 unicode codepoints will take between 3-6 words + 15-60 bytes, so around 39-108 bytes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum elements of a list depend's on the memory of the system and whether you're using Erlang/OTP 32 or 64 bit. You can calculate the Memory Size of the list from the information below

**Memory Size list Data Type:**

```
1 word + 1 word per element + the size of each element.
```

more information can be found about the [Memory & System limit](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html) from this [link](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html)